# Passing user input with quotes as parameters to function in bash

Tags: bash

I'd like to pass user input that includes quotes and spaces (for example: a "b c") to bash function properly and can't find a way to do I do that.

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

myFunction () {
    echo "Parameter 1: $1"
    echo "Parameter 2: $2"
}

read -p "Enter parameters: " parameters
myFunction $parameters
```

When I run above and input a "b c" the result is following:

```
$ ./test.sh 
Enter parameters: a "b c"
Parameter 1: a
Parameter 2: "b
```

Quotes are ignored. Parameters are broken by spaces.

Wrapping variable in quotes (`myFunction "$parameters"`) does not help either as the whole string including quotes would become `$1` while `$2` would be empty.

What I need is that `$1=="a"` and `$2=="b c"` but I can't find how to make bash to glue `"b` and `c"` together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want isn't something you should usually do, you can however use `eval` to get the desired result:

```
eval "myFunction $parameters"
```

You should rater just accept them as arguments for your script:

```
% cat my_script.bash
#!/bin/bash
myFunction() {
    echo "Parameter 1: $1"
    echo "Parameter 2: $2"
}
myFunction "$@"
```

And call it with:

```
% ./my_script.bash a "b c"
Parameter 1: a
Parameter 2: b c
```

Another thing that is wrong is that you didn't quotes `$parameters`, this will make it undergo [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) and [globbing](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs), and `myFunction` will be called like this:

```
myFunction 'a' '"b' 'c"'
```

Full code:

```
#!/bin/bash
myFunction () {
    echo "Parameter 1: $1"
    echo "Parameter 2: $2"
}

read -rp "Enter parameters: " parameters
eval "myFunction $parameters"
```

I also jammed a `-r` on read to treat backslashes literally.

Comment: Thanks eval worked. My script is an interactive cli which is why I needed to use "read" rather than using script params which would be much easier.